# How to set content with line break and html tags in tinyEditor

Tags: php, html, mysql, tinymce

I am saving the content of the **tinymce editor** in MySQL table, and would like to paste the same content that I have retrieved from the database back in the editor.
I use the **htmlentities()** function to encode the input, save it into the database and then decode the content with **html_entity_decode()** before displaying it.
`<?php echo html_entity_decode($content->post); ?>`
will output:

```
<p>adf adf adfadf aadf <img src="images/k0RpgvZ.png" alt="image" width="27" height="18" /></p>
```

I am facing two issues:

1. How to display this content as html, not just as text ?
2. I would also like to set the content of the tinyEditor with this value retrieved from the database.
   This code snippet does it (taken from [tiny blog](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/how-to-get-content-and-set-content-in-tinymce/)).

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#myTextarea',
    setup: function (editor) {
      editor.on('init', function (e) {
        editor.setContent('<?php echo $content->post; ?>');
      });
    }
  });
```

However, it only works when `$content->post` contents a single word (no space, no line break, no special character).
As soon as there is a line break, or a space,..., I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break
```

How to handle those issues ?

Comment: Use ` insted of '. Try this: editor.setContent(`<?php echo $content->post; ?>`);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
editor.setContent(`<?php echo $content->post; ?>`);
```

Comment: Thank you @KHIMAJI, data are now set in the editor. But there are in plain text, like this : `<p>adf adf adfadf aadf <img src="images/k0RpgvZ.png" alt="image" width="27" height="18" /></p>
`

Comment: Can you please remove "html_entity_decode" function and check?

Comment: Check without using "htmlentities" and "html_entity_decode" function.

Comment: I use  `htmlentities()` before saving it into the database. So it converts some characters to HTML entities. And I would like to use `htmlentities()` before saving it into the database for security issues.

Comment: Then you need to check "html_entity_decode" is executing and replacing proper variable and it displays after "html_entity_decode". As per your explanation then content is showing without using "html_entity_decode" function.

Comment: Unfortunately with or without `html_entity_decode` and ` htmlentities` only plain text content is showed.

Comment: Are you using any blade framework? or any other framework for view?

Comment: It is alright now. I am using `htmlspecialchars`. Thank you again for your support.